# How to check if a browser does not allow HTML5 video auto play?

Tags: mobile, youtube-api, html5-video

Some browsers such as Chrome on Android and iOS Safari do not allow HTML5 videos to be auto-played or played via scripts. Is there a way to test this in javascript without succumbing to user agent sniffing?